# HTML issue - images not showing in Chrome web browser

Tags: html

I am very new to using HTML so please bear with me on this one.

I can't get images to show on a basic piece of code as per below. I have tried using the full file path. I have checked security settings, permissions, and ensured that I can open all types of web sites.

I have a folder called HTML and in this folder is the file with the code TestPhoto.HTML and in the HTML folder is a sub directory called img and in this folder is the JPEG file books.jpg

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h2>HTML Image</h2>

<img src=“/img/books.jpg” alt=“Notebooks” width=“725” height=“543”>
</img>
</body>
</html>
```

The image never shows even if I try other images

I would really welcome some help with this issue.

Comment: try `src="img/books.jpg" instead. A leading slash in a partial URL means search from the root of the server; without slash means relative to the current page.

Comment: you use “ ” character change all with " "

Comment: thank you dki, sadegh and jhnc for your help, it was the quotes and the slash...it works well now....I'm learning!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you used the [Left Double Quotation Mark (U+201C)](https://unicode-table.com/en/201C/) instead of the standard ASCII [Quotation Mark (U+0022)](https://unicode-table.com/en/0022/) for the quotes. You might find usefull to disable the autocompletion for the quotes or try an other software to write your HTML code.

I fixed the quotes for you:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h2>HTML Image</h2>

<img src="/img/books.jpg" alt="Notebooks" width="725" height="543">
</img>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: dki - Thank you very much for this advice as it worked ! I would never have spotted this.